# Swap position of number in a 4 digit number without array

Tags: javascript

in 4 digit number how to swap 1 number with 3 and 2 with 4 number
I need to solve one problem in javascript.Thank you

Comment: Look up how substrings work.  You can grab any single character and write it to a new string.  And you can do this without converting it to an array.

Comment: This seems like a homework question; nobody is going to do your homework for you. You should be looking at ways to do this using math, read up on the modulus operator (`%`).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
x = '1234'

x.replace(/(.)(.)(.)(.)/,'$3$4$1$2')

result: "3412"
```

Comment: Ha.  Wow.  That's a wild solution.  :0

Comment: And works with hex and binary string numbers too :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple answer using no arrays:

```
<div id="demo">

</div>

var vals="1234"

res = vals.charAt(3) 
res += vals.charAt(2) 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res
```

In short, you can put a new string together, and order the characters however you wish.

Comment: I think given `1234`, the OP wants to swap 1,3 and 2,4, ending up with `3412`. This code will return `43` and drop the other two digits completely.

Comment: Oh, c'mon...  I was giving an example how he could do anything he wanted with the string.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, but (IMO) you should say that, to avoid confusing readers who don't already understand what the code should do.

Comment: Understood.  But he didn't ask specifically for that exact string to be changed.  He was looking for how to swap characters.